# JQuery Adding a Child Div to a Parent without changing the Parents Height

Tags: jquery

I'm using JQuery to load an image into a div (myCanvas) which works great. I then want to load a child div and place it in the top left corner, sounds simple but the image in the parent is shifted down. Every new child div added futher moves the image down

```
i++;
var myChildDiv = $('<div id="child' + i + '"class="draggable"></div>');
myChildDiv.css({ position: 'relative', top: '0px', left: '0px' });
$('#myCanvas').append(myChildDiv);
```

Please can someone advise as to how to avoid the image being shifted.
Many thanks

Comment: I think you should use absolute positioning for that.

Comment: I figured this out, just made the child div absolute positioning :-)

Comment: Hey Shikkediel, thanks for the reply and yes you're right. thanks

Comment: Cheers, you may want to keep in mind that if you want to absolutely position an element inside it's parent, that parent will need to be specified as having been positioned as well. Anything goes as long as it's not static or the absolute child will ignore it.